# or_where is not working in codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, between

I have a query model.But the second or_where is not working

**model**

```
    $this->db->select('st_student.st_id');
    $this->db->from('st_student'); 
    $this->db->where('st_status',1);
    $this->db->or_where('st_status',2);  
    if(($from!='') && ($to!='')){  
        $this->db->where("ab_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");
        $this->db->or_where("as_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");
    } 
    $this->db->group_by('st_student.st_id');    
    $result=$this->db->get();
```

**sql query**

```
SELECT `st_student`.`st_id`
FROM (`st_student`)
WHERE `st_status` =  1
OR `st_status` =  2
AND `ab_date` BETWEEN '01/15/2016' AND '01/26/2016'
AND `as_date` BETWEEN '01/15/2016' AND '01/26/2016'
GROUP BY `st_student`.`st_id`
```

Whats wrong in that

Comment: The problem with actually editing the OP's original post is that we don't know whether the error was coming from that small syntax error or not - perhaps the OP would like to comment?

Comment: @Rose are you getting syntax error or you are NOT getting expected result?

Comment: i'm not getting expected result..run my query in mysql.i put paranthesis between where clause..that time got correct result

Comment: @Rose- the code you originally posted had a missing apostrophe from the very first line - was this code copied directly from your script and pasted like that?

Comment: @Rose What is in `$from` and `$to`

Comment: date in mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: echo it and post the values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not getting expected result because the query is not having brackets for conditions.

Try as below :

```
$status_condition = 'st_status = 1 or st_status = 2';
$this->db->select('st_student.st_id');
$this->db->from('st_student');
$this->db->where($status_condition);
if(($from!='') && ($to!=''))
{
    $date_condition = "((ab_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."') or (as_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'))";
    $this->db->where($date_condition);
}
$this->db->group_by('st_student.st_id');
$result=$this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `or_where_in`

```
$this->db->select('st_student.st_id');
$this->db->from('st_student'); 
$this->db->where('st_status',1);
$this->db->or_where('st_status',2);  
if((!empty($from)) && (!empty($to)))
{  
    $this->db->where('ab_date BETWEEN date("$from", "Y/m/d H:i:s") AND date("$to", "Y/m/d H:i:s") ');
    $this->db->or_where_in('as_date BETWEEN date("$from", "Y/m/d H:i:s") AND date("$to", "Y/m/d H:i:s") ');
} 
$this->db->group_by('st_student.st_id');    
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$this->db->where("st_status = 1 or st_status = 2")
```

instead of

```
$this->db->where('st_status',1);

$this->db->or_where('st_status',2);
```

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('st_student.st_id');
$this->db->from('st_student');
$this->db->where('st_status',1, FALSE);
$this->db->or_where('st_status',2, NULL, FALSE);
if(($from!='') && ($to!='')){
    $this->db->where("ab_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'", FALSE);
    $this->db->or_where("as_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'", NULL, FALSE);
}
$this->db->group_by('st_student.st_id');
$result=$this->db->get();
```